# Show this text when a document field is empty

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

I am having trouble in the documentSnapshot. I want to show "No data" when the document field is empty. And show "has data" when the document field has something inside. The problem is that either when the document field has something inside or not it’s always showing "no data"[image]

```
class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  String userUid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(userUid)
        .snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.data?.data()?.containsValue('groupId') ==null) {
        return const Text("no data");
      } else {
        //It’s always show this
        return const Text('has data');
      }
    });
    }
}
```

Comment: There is probably an error in the stream.

Comment: What do you mean?. Because in my code there’s no error or anything.

Comment: Check if a document exists: https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/exists.html.

Comment: The thing is I don’t want to check If the doc exist. I want to check If the doc field is empty or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are checking here if the document field is null or not but you need to check whether the field is empty string("") or not since thats how picture shows.

**change this line**

if (snapshot.data?.data()?.containsValue('groupId') == null)

containsValue is checking if the object from firebase which is something like key and value pair,  contains the given [value], in this case 'groupId'. but groupId is key not value from picture shown in your case

**try this**

```
String userUid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
bool checkEmpty = false;
StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
          stream: firestore
              .collection('users')
              .doc("userUid")
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            snapshot.data!.data()?.forEach((key, value) {
              if (key == 'groupId') {
                checkEmpty = value == '';
              }
            });
            return checkEmpty?
                  const Text('no data'):
                  const Text('has data')
```

Comment: It’s still the same. It says this `Equality operator '==' invocation with references of unrelated types.` And I tried  `// ignore: unrelated_type_equality_checks` But nothing change.

Comment: _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)
                   `return checkEmpty!
                  ? const Text('no data')
                  : const Text('has data');`

Comment: have you checked checkEmpty value in the if clause, please share your code

Comment: I ve share my code above .

Comment: check it again, just edited it

Comment: Omg!! Its work thank you so much . You have no idea how long I ve been working on this problem.

Comment: yes, no problem my friend https://dart.dev/codelabs/null-safety. read about null safety here.