# how can I read the data in field from the firestore, so that the data read can be checked whether it is "" or not?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on creating a seat booking website, and currently trying to make a system that allows users to click on a seat, and when they press submit, the website will read the firestore database to check whether the seat is empty or not, then it will update the empty fields to indicate it has been occupied.So basically, I want to read the field inside a document so that I can check whether it is empty or not. What I mean by empty is not that there is nothing on it, but the stored data is "".[image]This is the database that I've created, where the documents are the seats and in each seats there is the field email.

```
import { authService, dbService } from "myBase";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Auth from "./Auth";

const Ticketing = () => {
    //initializes the variables that are going to be taken in, initializing the information that will be selected by the user
    const [seat1, selectSeat1] = useState();
    const [seat2, selectSeat2] = useState();
    const [performance, selectPerformance] = useState("");
    const [seat, selectSeat] = useState("");
    const user = authService.currentUser;
    const userEmail = user.email;
    const [Empty, isEmpty] = useState();
    const onSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
            if(dbService.collection(performance).doc(seat).get(email) === ""){
                isEmpty(true);
            }
            else{
                isEmpty(false);
            }

        if(Empty === true){
            const ticketingDB = dbService.collection(performance).doc(seat);
            return ticketingDB.set(
                {email:userEmail}
            )

        }
        else if(Empty === false){
            console.log("not available");
        }
        selectPerformance("");
        selectSeat("");
    }

    return(
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
             <div onClick={() => selectPerformance("performance-1")}>
                Performance 1
            </div>
            <div onClick={() => selectPerformance("performance-2")}>
                Performance 2
            </div>
            <row>
                <div onClick={() => selectSeat("a1")}>1</div>
                <div onClick={() => selectSeat("a2")}>2</div>
                <div onClick={() => selectSeat("a3")}>3</div>
                <div onClick={() => selectSeat("a4")}>4</div>
            </row>
            
            <span>{performance}</span>
            <span>{seat}</span>
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
        
    )


};
export default Ticketing;
```

Comment: please check the Stackoverflow link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72588877/show-this-text-when-a-document-field-is-empty

Comment: Which Firestore library are you using, "myBase" is not clear?